# C++ Member variable losing value after constructor

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading

I'm having a problem in one of my classes. I have these 2 classes, GameApp and Simulation:

**GameApp.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "Simulation.h"

class Simulation;

class GameApp {

    static GameApp *instance;

public:

    ~GameApp(void);

    static GameApp *initializeContext(const char *gameTitle, const int windowWidth, const int windowHeight);

    //void setSimulation(Simulation &simulation) { *(this->simulation) = simulation; }
    Simulation *getSimulation() { return simulation; }

    static const int TARGET_FPS = 50; // Frames per second

private:

    GameApp(void);
    Simulation *simulation;

    double frameIntervalList[TARGET_FPS]; // A list containing the time to render the last 60 frames
    // Other stuff that doesn't matter
```

**Simulation.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include "GameApp.h"

class Simulation {
public:
    Simulation(void);
    Simulation(const Simulation &copy);
    ~Simulation(void);

    Simulation &operator=(const Simulation &other);

protected:
    std::vector<Entity*> *entities;
```

And, in **GameApp.cpp**, in the function `initializeContext`, I have:

```
#include "GameApp.h"

GameApp *GameApp::instance = NULL;

GameApp::GameApp() {
    gamePaused = false;
    frameIntervalSum = 0;
    this->simulation = new Simulation();
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        frameIntervalList[i] = 0;
    }
}

GameApp *GameApp::initializeContext(const char *gameTitle, const int windowWidth, const int windowHeight) {
    instance = new GameApp();

    // (...) Rest of initialize funcion
}
```

The problem is, for some misterious reason, when I call `initializeContext`, the first line of it calls GameApp's constructor, which creates a new Simulation, which allocates correctly and I get a memory address for the simulation pointer. But when the program exits the constructor of GameApp, in the line right after `instance = new GameApp();`, if I check the `simulator` variable on the newly created `instance` using the debugger, I get the pointer value of `0x00000000`, and the `Simulation` that I just created is gone. This would indeed happen if I was using the stack memory on the constructor, but I'm clearly using `new`, creating the new Simulation variable in the correct way, I guess. What may be happening here?

Also, there's a commented `setSimulation` function on the `GameApp.h` file. When I leave this uncommented, I get the compiler error 2582, "operator= function is unavailable in Simulation". Can this be related to my problem?

**EDIT:** The problem was indeed the for loop with the hardcoded size. I changed the size of `frameIntervalList` from 60 to 50 in the header but forgot to change it on the loop. Also updated code to show the declaration of `frameIntervalList`.

Comment: Everything seems to be OK. All I can think of is that your `frameIntervalList` initialzer loop uses a wrong hardcoded `60` as the size and this may overwrite things if it overindexes but other than that... Check that loop please.

Comment: The `operator=` compile error happens because you put the implementation of `setSimulation()` into the header file where you have only the forward declaration of the `Simulation` class. Put the body of `setSimulation()` to the .cpp and in the .cpp include the header file where `Simulation` is declared.

Comment: @pasztorpisti nm. you're right. the app includes the simulation with includes the app. duh. gotta reloc that member (and make sure its implemented).

Comment: @WhozCraig You are right, after seeing the forward declaration my eye stopped and I haven't noticed the include 2 lines above... :-) :-) :-)

Comment: @pasztorpisti actually, ***you're*** right. The A includes B includes A is fenced correctly, but it means someone needs a forward decl, and by the looks of it its Simulation. up ticked your comment.

Comment: @WhozCraig Its indeed a circular include bug... hmmm :-) better and better

Comment: @pasztorpisti Thanks! Your guess about the loop was correct. I have a const int called TARGET_FPS, which I'm using to define the size of the array but for some reason wasn't using on the loop. Everything was working until I changed that value to 50. Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @pasztorpisti yeah, but at least its pragma fenced. could be worse. hurry up and write an answer so i can uptick it =P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only code that executes between the initialization of the `simulation` member variable and the code that comes after the `GameApp` ctor is the for loop that initialzes `frameIntervalList` so its initialization with a hardcoded size might overwrite the value of `simulation` variable if you are unlucky. (Or lucky because it helps you to catch a very ugly bug early!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when calling a parameterized constructor from a default constructor to initialize my class members. Instead of initializing **GameApp** class data members this way, try using an initializer list to initialize any members that will call other constructors. It worked for me!